# Use Haskell through GHCI alone?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

I'm totally new to Haskell, so this is a soft question, but it seems that most tutorials for Haskell define a main function, compile it, and then execute the program as a whole from the command line.

I'm coming from more of an R/Julia/Python background where I feel most comfortable working within a REPL or sending lines to the REPL from an editor.

I'm wondering if it is possible to be a Haskell programmer using GHCI alone? I am having difficult following most of the tutorials on Haskell within the interpreter for some reason. Is code written to be executed within the interpreter different from code that is compiled i.e. does the interpreter require special syntax?

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference between Interpreted code and compiled code. What examples are you running into that don't work in ghci?

Comment: The ghci repl works differently in a number of subtle (e.g. defaulting rules) and not-so-subtle ways, and for various reasons is not very nice to interactively build a program in in my experience (multi-line definitions are clumsy to write, difficult to edit when you realize you forgot to add a `let`, etc.). IMHO you will have a better experience working on a `.hs` file and loading/reloading/playing with it in ghci

Comment: The interpreter only requires a different syntax for code actually typed into the REPL - if you write a Haskell source file and load it into GHCi, the syntax is identical. The code you enter into GHCi is essentially scoped as if it were in one big `do` block, except top level declarations are allowed (excluding top level function declarations).

Comment: In case you're not aware of it: typing `:e` in ghci will open your editor of choice and the module will be reloaded once you leave the editor. It makes it a lot easier to write multi-line definitions for instance.

Comment: The best way to build Haskell programs interactively is using an editor like emacs that offers good Haskell support. This will give you the source in one pane and GHCi in another, along with all sorts of other assistance.

Answer (score 0):

### TL; DR

In order to use GHCi, all definitions (`... = ...`) must be prefixed by `let` - e.g `let ... = ...`.

---

GHCi does have a subtly different syntax to regular Haskell. This is to accommodate the use of IO in the REPL.

For the most part, the syntax of GHCi is the same as the syntax for a `do` block in the IO monad:
Definitions can be made via `let` syntax:

```
let f x = 10
```

and IO actions can be sequenced:

```
print 1
```

When this is submitted to GHCi, it will be immediately performed - i.e `let` definitions are bound and IO actions are performed.

However, the subtle differences come from GHCi's other function: evaluation expressions. If you type in an expression that is not an IO action, for instance:

```
1 + 3
```

GHCi will attempt to print the result of the expression. i.e, it will execute:

```
print $ 1 + 3
```